# cannot bind values to dynamically created textbox jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

i'm trying to bind jquery autocomplete result to dynamically created textboxes, i have searched internet and forums but couldn't found any appropriate solution, i'm sharing my code

JQUERY:

```
function bindAutoComplete(classname) {
    $("." + classname).autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Admin/Ticket/GetPart',
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        if (data.length > 0) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return { label: item.PartNumber, value: item.PartNumber };
                            }))
                        }
                        else {
                            response([{ label: 'No results found.' }]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        },
    });

}

function bindData() {
    var errormsg = "";
    var amount = $('.inputs').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Admin/Ticket/GetPart',
        data: { 'term': amount },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != null) {
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    $('#Manufacturer').val(data[1].Manufacturer);
                    $('#DateCode').val(data[0].DateCode);
                    $('#Package').val(data[0].PackageCase);
                    $('.buyingprice').val(data[0].Price);
                }
                else {
                    $('#Manufacturer').val('');
                    $('#DateCode').val('');
                    $('#Package').val('');
                    $('.buyingprice').val('');
                }
            }

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            $('#error').html(jqXHR)
        }
    });
};

// fetch part number
$(document).ready(function () {
    bindAutoComplete('inputs');
    $('.inputs').keyup(bindData)
});

$("#AddMore").click(function () {

    $("#maintable").each(function () {

        var tds = '<tr>';

        jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
            tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
        });
        tds += '</tr>';

        if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {

            $('tbody', this).append(tds);
         //   bindData();
            bindAutoComplete('inputs');
            $("#delete").fadeIn('200');
        }
        else {
            $(this).append(tds);
            bindAutoComplete('inputs');
        //    bindData();

        }
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<table id="maintable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Part No
                </th>
                <th>
                    MFG
                </th>
                <th>
                    DC
                </th>
                <th>
                    PKG
                </th>
                <th>
                    QTY. Need
                </th>
                <th>
                    QTY. Offer
                </th>
                <th>
                    BP
                </th>
                <th>
                    BP(USD)
                </th>
                <th>
                    AMT (USD)
                </th>
                <th>
                    LT Days
                </th>
                <th>
                    Desc
                </th>
                <th>
                    Note
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input class="inputs" type="text" name="abcd" id="PartNumber23" style="width:130px;" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="text-box single-line" id="Manufacturer" name="Manufacturer" type="text" value="" />
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Manufacturer" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="text-box single-line" id="DateCode" name="DateCode" type="text" value="" />
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="DateCode" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="text-box single-line" id="Package" name="Package" type="text" value="" />
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Package" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Quantity must be a number." data-val-required="The Quantity field is required." id="Quantity" name="Quantity" style="width:35px;" type="number" value="" />
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Quantity" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="text-box single-line" id="CustomQuantity" name="CustomQuantity" style="width:35px;" type="text" value="" />
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="CustomQuantity" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="buyingprice text-box single-line" id="BuyingPrice" name="BuyingPrice" type="text" value="" />
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="BuyingPrice" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="bpusd" name="ConvertedBP" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="" />
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ConvertedBP" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="amtusd" name="ConvertedAmount" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="" />
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ConvertedAmount" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    <span id="error" class="error"></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="LTDays" name="LTDays" type="text" value="" />
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="LTDays" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="drop" id="Description" name="Description">
                        <option>Original ROHS</option>
                        <option>ROHS Compliance</option>
                    </select>
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Description" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <textarea class="txtarea text-box multi-line" id="Note" name="Note" placeholder="Any Note With Ticket"></textarea>
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Note" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

it is working perfectly on a single row of textbox but not working on dynamic text boxes, please guide me i'm really stuck on this from hours

Comment: The problem is that `autocomplete` is basically a jQuery plugin, so can only be applied to elements that exist. You need to explicitly apply it to any loaded elements (that do not already have it... many plugins do not cope with being run twice).

Comment: you cannot have multiple elements with the same id on the page, if you do the jQuery selector will only pick up the first element with that id.  If you are trying to bind the results to the last row added then you may want to use `$('#maintable tbody > tr:last .classOfInputHere')`.  Also instead of just looping through the tds and appending the html like that, why not just clone the last row and append the clone

Comment: autocomplete is working correctly on dynamically generated textboxes but i want to bind the JSON response to other textboxes and it is not working with dynamic text boxes but only one textbox

Comment: @Pete i want to bind the json result to dynamic text boxes it is only working on a single text box which is not dynamically generated but not working on dynamic generated text boxes

Comment: yes it won't do, you are using ids, read my comment

Comment: @Pete can u please tell me how i can do this? because i'm really helpless and stuck here from hours :(

Comment: @Pete i have tried using classes but didn't get success

Comment: did you use `#maintable tbody > tr:last ` before your class names to make sure it was the last one that was updated? you would also need to to that to the `amount` variable and in front of the selector where you bind autocomplete - as trueblue says you cannot bind it to the elements that have already had it bound

Comment: @Pete where i can use this?

Comment: @Pete when i use class it will bind the same value to all textboxes i don't want same value in all textboxes